Does RAID always read/write an entire chunk?
Many resources on the internet contain conflicting information regarding read/write logic for RAID chunks.
This answer contains the following (seemingly conflicting) pieces of information:

A 512 KB chunk size doesn't require system to write e.g. 512 KB for every 4 KB write or to read 512 KB of device surface for a 4 KB application read.


[When reading a 16-KiB block from RAID with a 64-KiB chunk size] the RAID will perform a read/modify/write operation when writing that 4-KiB file/16-KiB block because the RAID's smallest unit of storage is 64-KiB.

On the other hand, this resource contains the following pieces of information:

For example, if you have a 10 KB text file and the chunk size is 256 KB, then that 10 KB of data is stored in a 256 KB block, with the rest of the block left empty. Conversely, with 16 KB chunks, there is much less wasted space when storing that 10 KB file.

In particular, I have the following questions:

When reading/writing some unit of data smaller than the RAID chunk size using a scheme without parity, does this require a read/modify/write operation for the entire chunk, or only the part of the chunk that is modified?
When using a RAID scheme with parity, does this change anything in the answer to question 1?
As alluded to in the second reference, does writing a unit of data smaller than the RAID chunk somehow leave the rest of the RAID chunk empty? This seems incorrect to me, but I wanted to clarify as this resource quite unambiguously states this.
Do any of these answers change depending on the RAID implementation (Linux kernel, hardware RAID, etc.)?

If possible, providing some sort of authoritative reference (some RAID specification, source code, etc.) would be awesome.
Thanks in advance!

Please edit your question to clarify whether you're asking about mirrored/striped RAID configurations (RAID0, RAID1, or RAID10), or about checksummed RAID configurations (RAID4, RAID5, RAID6).  The presence/absence of checksum blocks will very likely affect how much of the chunk is written/rewritten on the physical disks.

I've updated my question to clarify the difference between items 1. (without parity) and 2. (with parity).

@PhilipCouling I didn't get the impression that the OP knew the difference and wanted answers for both cases.  The question was worded as if all RAID types behave the same way with respect to slicing/chunking of reads and writes.  I thought the OP had a specific use case in mind (although it was not stated in the question) and desired the answer for that use case.

@PhilipCouling I don't agree that it's the right thing to explain all possible use cases in the answer to a vague question.  I favor asking for clarification and then giving an answer relevant to the clear user case.  It looks like you don't agree with me on that point.  That's okay, you asked me about it and I answered.

@SottoVoce I wasn't suggesting enumerating all possible use cases, and this question is not vague. I was saying that if you know a specific detail makes a difference and there are a tiny handful of options, better to explain that in an answer than have the user guess what they need. Since there's now and answer pointing out that different RAID type does not affect the answer, it rather proves my point that the question was not at all vague and did not need this information adding.

The chunk size primarily determines how data is distributed across devices (which physical device and offset to look for if you want to read byte 1234567890 on your RAID device).
It does not directly affect the RAID algorithm, which in case of RAID 5 is a simple XOR operation, also known as bitwise XOR. Mathematically this operates on bits and as such does not depend on bytes, sectors or chunks. RAID 6 is a bit more involved but still similar enough.
As such there is no need to process the entire chunk.
For Linux mdadm RAID, you can try to verify it experimentally:

Create some virtual drives (using sparse files):
# truncate -s 1G {1..8}.img
# for img in {1..8}.img; do losetup --find --show "$img"; done
/dev/loop{1..8}

Put a mdadm RAID 6 on top (using --assume-clean so it writes nothing, other than metadata):
# mdadm --create --assume-clean --level=6 --raid-devices=8 --data-offset=2048 /dev/md42 /dev/loop{1..8}
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md42 started.

Small write to a random offset:
# blockdev --getsize64 /dev/md42
6429868032
# echo $((SRANDOM % 6429868032))
2931013558
# echo -n TEST | dd bs=1 seek=2931013558 of=/dev/md42
# sync
# echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

Result:
# filefrag {1..8}.img
1.img: 1 extent found
2.img: 1 extent found
3.img: 2 extents found
4.img: 1 extent found
5.img: 2 extents found
6.img: 2 extents found
7.img: 1 extent found
8.img: 1 extent found

All images have 1 extent (for mdadm metadata), so you can ignore it. Only 3 images have 2 extents (data, parity 1, parity 2). So only these have been written to.
# filefrag -v -e 3.img 5.img 6.img
File size of 3.img is 1073741824 (262144 blocks of 4096 bytes)
 ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
   0:        1..       1:     301057..    301057:      1:          1: merged
   1:   119739..  119739:     318395..    318395:      1:     420795: last,merged
3.img: 2 extents found

As you can see, the extent is a single sector, not a chunk.
Raw data looks like this:
# hexdump -C 3.img
*
1d3bb7b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 54 45  53 54 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......TEST......|
1d3bb7c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
# hexdump -C 5.img
*
1d3bb7b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 54 45  53 54 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......TEST......|
1d3bb7c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
# hexdump -C 6.img
*
1d3bb7b0  00 00 00 00 00 00 29 24  59 29 00 00 00 00 00 00  |......)$Y)......|
1d3bb7c0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*

Because all data is zero, RAID 5 parity of TEST is still TEST. For RAID6 parity, TEST turned into )$Y).

You can extend this experiment by filling the array with random data, then only write {4,16,512,4096,16384} bytes of zero at/around the targeted offset for only one or several out of these 3 devices, then repeat the experiment.
This way you can determine that mdadm is not operating at single byte level resolution (but still not going beyond sectors, not to mention entire chunks).
You might also notice that it writes the wrong parity if parity was already wrong before write (parity updated using parity instead of recalculating from data).

This possibly misses one subtle point on RAID[4,5,6]. The block/stipe size can affect the quantity of parity data being written.  Using terms "block" to mean data on a single disk and "stripe" to mean collection of blocks across all disks:  If the data being written is no more than one block then double the data will be written in RAID[4,5]. Once for the data once for the parity. But if more than one block's worth of data is written within the same stripe then less parity will be written.  EG for RAID 5 this could only be 50% parity for 3 disks or 25% for 5 disks.

Thanks very much for user https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30851/frostschutz how to simple play with RAIDs, without the needs to buy a lot of controllers and disks, first :-)
To answer the specific questions asked:

Please differentiate between read-modify-writes required by the RAID operation and read-modify-writes required by the file system. The later can happen, when a write() system call writes data, that starts or ends in the middle of a disk sector, and that sector is not present in the memory set aside as disk cache. Such events are rare, though: Most normal applications write to the end of files, only, and the Linux file system cache keeps around half-filled sectors at the end of files open for writing with high priority. Most database applications do write in the middle of files, but usually by performing a read-modify-write operation in user space. The sectors just read() will again usually still be around at the time, that the database issues the corresponding write() to update a dataset or index entry.
The size of the sectors, that the file system reads or writes, is not changed by a RAID between the file system and the disk. All reads and writes still occur on sectors, not on chunks or stripes!

On non-parity RAID, neither sector reads nor writes need any additional read-modify-write cycles. All, what is necessary, is to map each logical sector number from the RAID to the actual physical disk(s) and sector number(s) of those disks. For RAID0, this is a 1 : 1 mapping, so each read() or write() of a sector from/to the RAID0 becomes a read() of a sector from/to one of the disks in the RAID0. For RAID1 and RAID10, this is a 1 : N mapping, where N is the concurrency of the RAID. For a read(), the system maps it to just one of the disks in the RAID1/10. It can apply some performance enhancing methods to choose an optimal disks, like one, that already has requests pending for physical sectors close to the one requested now, or otherwise to a disk, that has a low count of pending requests. For a write(), all the mapped sectors will be written to keep the redundancy.
But again, no data from the remainder of a stripe needs to be read or written to read or update just some sectors inside a stripe.

On parity-enabled RAID, in particular RAID5 and RAID6 (nobody should be using RAID4 anymore), all logical reads from the RAID again directly map to a specific sector on a physical disk and only that sector is written. In the (rare) case, that the read hits a failed disk, all the matching sectors on the non-failed disks and at least one parity disk (or both parity disks in case of two failed disks on a RAID6) and the sector has to be reconstructed.
On logical writes to a RAID5/6, the system has to write the actual sector to the very disk, that it is mapped to, but also update parity on the one (RAID5) or two (RAID6) disks, that carry the parity for that particular sector. There are two ways for the parity update: Either, the system can read the matching sectors on all the other disks, that map to the same parity sector(s), and then re-calculate parity after having loaded all the data. Or it can read the old data of the sector, that is being updated, before overwriting it, and calculate the parity update (as a XOR operation) resulting from it. It can then read the old parity data from the parity disk(s), apply the parity update to it, and then write them out again. Of course, each of the reads in these read-modify-write operations can be left out, if the old data is already present in the memory cache.

The file system organizes data in sectors as the smallest unit. An underlying RAID's stripe size doesn't change this. No space will be lost, if the stripe size is larger than the sector size. Note, that total throughput tends to be a bit higher, if typical writes are exactly one stripe at a stripe boundary. So, if the RAID is for example directly used with a database (with no file system between), it may make sense to match the stripe size and the database's block size. For ext4 file systems, the "extsize" parameter should be set to RAID's stripe size, which will again prefer allocations aligned with the RAID's stripes. However, neither of these measures wastes space.

My answers refer to Linux software RAID. All decent hardware RAIDs will basically be the same, though. An additional feature of most hardware RAIDs are large cache memories, that store data to be written. Often, they contain backup batteries to keep the data in the cache alive in case of sudden power failures.


